# Boot custom kernel via phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, fastboot, kernel, overclocking

I can currently boot a custom kernel (without flashing it) for test purposes by using fastboot on my computer via:

```
cmd> fastboot boot customkernel.img
```

Which works great. I've found great kernels that do different things but have trade offs such as an overclocked gpu but the battery life takes a hit or an undervolted kernel but performance takes a hit.

So the kernels are great for different situations. But it would be great to use them for different situations without needing my computer. So if I wanted to use an game emulator I could boot into the gpu overclock or if I need battery life I could boot undervolted kernel.

**Is there a way to boot custom kernels via fastboot on the phone without needing an external computer to run cmd commands?**

Fastboot is defined as holding both volume up and volume down plus the power key. Not just holding volume up and power.

Comment: You should be able to flash kernels via ROM Manager? But this would be permanent until you reverted the kernel.

Comment: I was hoping just to find a boot option but I will have to use a rom manager if I can't find a viable alternative. I was unaware that a rom manager could do that, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My memory is rusty, but I used to switch between different kernels with my OG Droid a year or two ago. I specifically remember flashing via ROM Manager. You may be able to find some further info on XDA Forums